# How to replace part of string by position?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have this string: `ABCDEFGHIJ`

I need to replace from position 4 to position 5 with the string `ZX`

It will look like this: `ABCZXFGHIJ`

But not to use with `string.replace("DE","ZX")` - I need to use with **position**

How can I do it?

Comment: @TotZam - please check the dates. *This* one is older than the one you linked.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I usually look at the quality of the question and answers, not the dates, as said to do [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/297762). In this case, I seem to have made a mistake and clicked the wrong one to mark as duplicate, since the quality of this question is obviously better, and so I have flagged the other question.

Comment: @TotZam - ah, I did not know about that recommendation - thanks for pointing it out. (Though it is confusing to see something older reported as a duplicate of something newer, so in such a case, it would be worth explicitly explaining that you are marking as duplicate an OLDER question, because the linked one has better answers.)

Answer (score 232, accepted):

The easiest way to add and remove ranges in a string is to use the [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

```
var theString = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
var aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(theString);
aStringBuilder.Remove(3, 2);
aStringBuilder.Insert(3, "ZX");
theString = aStringBuilder.ToString();
```

An alternative is to use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx), but I think the `StringBuilder` code gets more readable.

Comment: would be better wrapping that up in an extension method :)

Comment: Why do you use a StringBuilder here? Check V4Vendetta's answer, which is much more readable...

Comment: @Fortega Remove() and Insert() each create and return a new string. The StringBuilder approach avoid this extra cost by working within a pre-allocated section of memory and moving chars round within it.

Comment: @redcalx That's true, but an extra cost is introduced by introducing a StringBuilder object and by reducing readability

Comment: What's the point of using StringBuilder here, if you're calling Remove and Insert the same way as V4Vendetta, but he is doing it directly on the string? Seems redundant code.

Comment: don't argue. if you do only one or two replacements, it probably does not matter and you can choose whatever variant you like best. However, if you do lots of replacements, you might want to use [Benchmark.NET](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) to figure out which method works best for your use case.

Answer (score 290):

```
string s = "ABCDEFGH";
s= s.Remove(3, 2).Insert(3, "ZX");
```

Comment: I do prefer this over initializing a new StringBuilder(...). Thanks!

Comment: I do not know why someone would use stringbuilder for this operation.  This is good answer

Answer (score 56):

### ReplaceAt(int index, int length, string replace)

Here's an extension method that doesn't use StringBuilder or Substring.  This method also allows the replacement string to extend past the length of the source string.

```
//// str - the source string
//// index- the start location to replace at (0-based)
//// length - the number of characters to be removed before inserting
//// replace - the string that is replacing characters
public static string ReplaceAt(this string str, int index, int length, string replace)
{
    return str.Remove(index, Math.Min(length, str.Length - index))
            .Insert(index, replace);
}
```

When using this function, if you want the entire replacement string to replace as many characters as possible, then set length to the length of the replacement string:

```
"0123456789".ReplaceAt(7, 5, "Hello") = "0123456Hello"
```

Otherwise, you can specify the amount of characters that will be removed:

```
"0123456789".ReplaceAt(2, 2, "Hello") = "01Hello456789"
```

If you specify the length to be 0, then this function acts just like the insert function:

```
"0123456789".ReplaceAt(4, 0, "Hello") = "0123Hello456789"
```

I guess this is more efficient since the StringBuilder class need not be initialized and since it uses more basic operations.  Please correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: Stringbuilder is more efficient if the string is longer than, say 200 characters.

Comment: No stress. Worked Straight up. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

If you care about performance, then the thing you want to avoid here are allocations. And if you're on .Net Core 2.1+, then you can, by using [the `string.Create` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.create?view=netcore-2.1):

```
public static string ReplaceAt(this string str, int index, int length, string replace)
{
    return string.Create(str.Length - length + replace.Length, (str, index, length, replace),
        (span, state) =>
        {
            state.str.AsSpan().Slice(0, state.index).CopyTo(span);
            state.replace.AsSpan().CopyTo(span.Slice(state.index));
            state.str.AsSpan().Slice(state.index + state.length).CopyTo(span.Slice(state.index + state.replace.Length));
        });
}
```

This approach is harder to understand than the alternatives, but it's the only one that will allocate only one object per call: the newly created string.

Answer (score 10):

Use `String.Substring()` (details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx)) to cut left part, then your replacement, then right part.  Play with indexes until you get it right :)

Something like:

```
string replacement=original.Substring(0,start)+
    rep+original.Substring(start+rep.Length);
```

Comment: I created three methods using the above three methods (string.Remove/Insert, Stringbuilder.Remove/Insert and Daniel's Substring answer, and SubString was the fastest method.

Answer (score 8):

```
        string s = "ABCDEFG";
        string t = "st";
        s = s.Remove(4, t.Length);
        s = s.Insert(4, t);
```

Comment: This works, you probably don't want to put `t` back again.

Answer (score 8):

As an extension method.

```
public static class StringBuilderExtension
{
    public static string SubsituteString(this string OriginalStr, int index, int length, string SubsituteStr)
    {
        return new StringBuilder(OriginalStr).Remove(index, length).Insert(index, SubsituteStr).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try something link this:

```
string str = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
str = str.Substring(0, 2) + "ZX" + str.Substring(5);
```

Answer (score 4):

Like other have mentioned the `Substring()` function is there for a reason:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "ABCDEFGHIJ";

    string output = input.Overwrite(3, "ZX"); // 4th position has index 3
    // ABCZXFGHIJ
}

public static string Overwrite(this string text, int position, string new_text)
{
    return text.Substring(0, position) + new_text + text.Substring(position + new_text.Length);
}
```

Also I timed this against the `StringBuilder` solution and got 900 tics vs. 875. So it is *slightly* slower.

Comment: @Aaron.S - no it does not. In my example `"ABCDEFGHIJ"` and `"ZX"` are of different lengths.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another

```
    public static string ReplaceAtPosition(this string self, int position, string newValue)        
    {
        return self.Remove(position, newValue.Length).Insert(position, newValue); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

With the help of this post, I create following function with additional length checks

```
public string ReplaceStringByIndex(string original, string replaceWith, int replaceIndex)
{
    if (original.Length >= (replaceIndex + replaceWith.Length))
    {
        StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder(original);
        rev.Remove(replaceIndex, replaceWith.Length);
        rev.Insert(replaceIndex, replaceWith);
        return rev.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Wrong lengths for the operation");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**All others answers don't work if the string contains Unicode char (like Emojis)** because an Unicode char weight more bytes than a char.

> *Example* : the emoji '' converted to bytes, will weight the equivalent of 2 chars. So, if the unicode char is placed at the beginning of your string, `offset` parameter will be shifted).

With [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656472/what-does-the-net-string-length-property-return-surrogate-neutral-length-or-co), i extend the StringInfo class to Replace by position keeping the Nick Miller's algorithm to avoid that :

```
public static class StringInfoUtils
{
    public static string ReplaceByPosition(this string str, string replaceBy, int offset, int count)
    {
        return new StringInfo(str).ReplaceByPosition(replaceBy, offset, count).String;
    }

    public static StringInfo ReplaceByPosition(this StringInfo str, string replaceBy, int offset, int count)
    {
        return str.RemoveByTextElements(offset, count).InsertByTextElements(offset, replaceBy);
    }

    public static StringInfo RemoveByTextElements(this StringInfo str, int offset, int count)
    {
        return new StringInfo(string.Concat(
            str.SubstringByTextElements(0, offset),
            offset + count < str.LengthInTextElements
                ? str.SubstringByTextElements(offset + count, str.LengthInTextElements - count - offset)
                : ""
            ));
    }
    public static StringInfo InsertByTextElements(this StringInfo str, int offset, string insertStr)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str?.String))
            return new StringInfo(insertStr);
        return new StringInfo(string.Concat(
            str.SubstringByTextElements(0, offset),
            insertStr,
            str.LengthInTextElements - offset > 0 ? str.SubstringByTextElements(offset, str.LengthInTextElements - offset) : ""
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/l0dqS5 I could not get other methods to fail on Unicode. Please alter the fiddle to demonstrate your use case. Very interested, in results.

Comment: @MarkusHooge Try to place the unicode chars at the beginning of your string like : https://dotnetfiddle.net/3V2K3Y. You'll see only the last line works well and place the char to the 4th place (in the other case, unicode char takes 2 char length)

Comment: You're right, it's not clear. I updated my answer to add more explanations why the others answer don't work

Answer (score 3):

```
string myString = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
string modifiedString = new StringBuilder(myString){[3]='Z', [4]='X'}.ToString();
```

Let me explain my solution.
Given the problem statement of altering a string in its two specific position (“position 4 to position 5”) with two character ‘Z’ and ‘X’ and the ask is to use the position index to alter the string and not string Replace() method(may be because of the possibility of repetition of some characters in the actual string), I would prefer to use minimalist approach to achieve the goal over using `Substring()` and string `Concat()` or string `Remove()` and `Insert()` approach. Though all those solutions will serve the purpose in attaining the same goal, but it just depends on personal choice and philosophy of settling with minimalist approach.
Coming back to my solution mention above, if we take a closer look of `string` and `StringBuilder`, both of them internally treats a given string as an array of characters. If we look at the implementation of `StringBuilder` it maintains an internal variable something like “`internal char[] m_ChunkChars;`” to capture the given string. Now since this is an internal variable, we cannot directly access the same. For external world, to be able to access and alter that character array, `StringBuilder` exposes them through indexer property which looks something like below

```
    [IndexerName("Chars")]
    public char this[int index]
    {
      get
      {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = this;
        do
        {
          // … some code
            return stringBuilder.m_ChunkChars[index1];
          // … some more code
        }
      }
      set
      {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = this;
        do
        {
            //… some code
            stringBuilder.m_ChunkChars[index1] = value;
            return;
            // …. Some more code
        }
      }
    }
```

My solution mentioned above leverage this indexer capability to directly alter the internally maintained character array which IMO is efficient and minimalist.

BTW; we can rewrite the above solution more elaborately something like below

```
 string myString = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
 StringBuilder tempString = new StringBuilder(myString);
 tempString[3] = 'Z';
 tempString[4] = 'X';
 string modifiedString = tempString.ToString();
```

In this context also would like to mention that in case of `string` it also have indexer property as a means to expose its internal character array, but in this case it only has Getter property (and no Setter) as string is immutable in nature. And that is why we need to use `StringBuilder` to alter the character array.

```
[IndexerName("Chars")]
public extern char this[int index] { [SecuritySafeCritical, __DynamicallyInvokable, MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)] get; }
```

And last but not the least this solution is only best fit for this specific problem where the ask is to replace only few characters with a known position index upfront. It may not be the best fit when the requirement is to alter a fairly lengthy string i.e. number of characters to alter are large in numbers.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how this code answers the question

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a solution with following requirements:

1. use only a single, one-line expression
2. use only system builtin methods (no custom implemented utility)

## Solution 1

The solution that best suits me is this:

```
// replace `oldString[i]` with `c`
string newString = new StringBuilder(oldString).Replace(oldString[i], c, i, 1).ToString();
```

This uses [`StringBuilder.Replace(oldChar, newChar, position, count)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.replace?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Text_StringBuilder_Replace_System_Char_System_Char_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

## Solution 2

The other solution that satisfies my requirements is to use `Substring` with concatenation:

```
string newString = oldStr.Substring(0, i) + c + oldString.Substring(i+1, oldString.Length);
```

This is OK too. I *guess* it's not as efficient as the first one performance wise (due to unnecessary string concatenation). But *premature optimization is the root of all evil*.

So pick the one that you like the most :)

Comment: Solution 2 works but requires correction:
string newString = oldStr.Substring(0, i) + c + oldString.Substring(i+1, oldString.Length-(i+1));

Comment: Better yet, just `string newString = oldStr.Substring(0, i) + c + oldString.Substring(i+1)`. By default without a length, .Substring will just pull the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we know the index of string to be replace.

```
    string s = "ABCDEFGDEJ";
    string z = "DE";
    int i = s.IndexOf(z);
    if(i == 3)
        s = s.Remove(3,z.Length).Insert(3,"ZX");
    //s = ABCZXFGDEJ
```

Answer (score 1):

hello this code helps me:

```
var theString = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
var aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(theString);
aStringBuilder.Remove(3, 2);
aStringBuilder.Insert(3, "ZX");
theString = aStringBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String timestamp = "2019-09-18 21.42.05.000705";
String sub1 = timestamp.substring(0, 19).replace('.', ':'); 
String sub2 = timestamp.substring(19, timestamp.length());
System.out.println("Original String "+ timestamp);      
System.out.println("Replaced Value "+ sub1+sub2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple extension method:

```cs
    public static class StringBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static StringBuilder Replace(this StringBuilder sb, int position, string newString)
            => sb.Replace(position, newString.Length, newString);

        public static StringBuilder Replace(this StringBuilder sb, int position, int length, string newString)
            => (newString.Length <= length)
                ? sb.Remove(position, newString.Length).Insert(position, newString)
                : sb.Remove(position, length).Insert(position, newString.Substring(0, length));
    }
```

Use it like this:

```cs
var theString = new string(' ', 10);
var sb = new StringBuilder(theString);
sb.Replace(5, "foo");
return sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this

```
Dim QTT As Double
                If IsDBNull(dr.Item(7)) Then
                    QTT = 0
                Else
                    Dim value As String = dr.Item(7).ToString()
                    Dim posicpoint As Integer = value.LastIndexOf(".")
                    If posicpoint > 0 Then
                        Dim v As New Text.StringBuilder(value)
                        v.Remove(posicpoint, 1)
                        v.Insert(posicpoint, ",")
                        QTT = Convert.ToDouble(v.ToString())
                    Else
                        QTT = Convert.ToDouble(dr.Item(7).ToString())
                    End If
                    Console.WriteLine(QTT.ToString())
                End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too.
**Edit**: I fixed the code so now it **really** works, thanks for pointing it out. Also the `source[...start]` returns a substring of `source` from index 0 to `start` (not including start) to and `source[end...]` works like that too but its from `end` to the end of the string. [More about ranges here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)
(Btw. this also works with arrays and lists to)

```
public static class ForStrings
{
    public static string ReplaceAt(this string source, int start, int end, string replacement)
    {
        return source[..start] + replacement + source[end..];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string OPsString = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
string newString = OPsString.ReplaceAt(3, 5, "ZX");
Console.WriteLine(newString); //"ABCZXFGHIJ"
```

Comment: The conversational parts (`Edit : I fixed the code...` in your edit [aren't needed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged) also, [ranges don't work with lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes#type-support-for-indices-and-ranges) "The List<T> supports indices but doesn't support ranges."

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use the `String.substr()`.

Like this:

```
ReplString = GivenStr.substr(0, PostostarRelStr)
           + GivenStr(PostostarRelStr, ReplString.lenght());
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe the simplest way would be this:(without stringbuilder)

```
string myString = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
char[] replacementChars = {'Z', 'X'};
byte j = 0;

for (byte i = 3; i <= 4; i++, j++)  
{                   
myString = myString.Replace(myString[i], replacementChars[j]);  
}
```

This works because a variable of type string can be treated as an array of char variables.
You can, for example refer to the second character of a string variable with name "myString" as myString[1]

Comment: This only works because in the author's example `string` the characters to be replaced each occur only once.  If you run this against, say, `"DBCDEFGHIE"` then you get `"ZBCZXFGHIX"`, which is not the desired result.  Also, I would not agree that this is simpler than the other non-`StringBuilder` solutions that were posted two and a half years ago.