# C# Replacing part of string by start and end position

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string and I want to replace a part of it.
The tricky part is that that I can't use Regex.replace, because I only know the start and end positions of the data in the string.
For example, if the string looks like this:

```
I love cats, some more stuff here, we dont know how much more
```

And I have `start=8` and `end=11`. And I want to replace that part to whatever I need to. This time lets say `dogs` so the new string will look like:

```
I love dogs, some more stuff here, we dont know how much more
```

How I could do that?

Comment: `mid$(myString, 9, 12) = "dogs"`  Oh, wait that's old VB/VBA.  Intersting how succinct it was, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to replace part of string by position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015593/how-to-replace-part-of-string-by-position)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace part of string by position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015593/how-to-replace-part-of-string-by-position)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
string replaced = original.Substring(0, start) + replacementText + 
                  original.Substring(end);
```

I had expected `StringBuilder` to have something which would do this, but I think you'd have to call `Remove` then `Insert`.

Comment: How about a `Remove` and then `Insert` on the `string`?

Comment: @Gabe: Yup, that would work - I think it would end up with fewer intermediate string values, but more copying. I think I'd also find this code simpler to understand :)

Answer (score 6):

```
str.Substring(0, 8) + "replacement" + str.Substring(11);
```

It's not "elegant", but it works.

Answer (score 2):

ReplaceAt(int index, int length, string replace)

Here's an extension method that doesn't use StringBuilder or Substring. This method also allows the replacement string to extend past the length of the source string.

```
//// str - the source string
//// index- the start location to replace at (0-based)
//// length - the number of characters to be removed before inserting
//// replace - the string that is replacing characters
public static string ReplaceAt(this string str, int index, int length, string replace)
{
    return str.Remove(index, Math.Min(length, str.Length - index))
            .Insert(index, replace);
}
```

When using this function, if you want the entire replacement string to replace as many characters as possible, then set length to the length of the replacement string:

```
"0123456789".ReplaceAt(7, 5, "Salut") = "0123456Salut"
```

Otherwise, you can specify the amount of characters that will be removed:

```
"0123456789".ReplaceAt(2, 2, "Salut") = "01Salut456789"
```

If you specify the length to be 0, then this function acts just like the insert function:

```
"0123456789".ReplaceAt(4, 0, "Salut") = "0123Salut456789"
```

I guess this is more efficient since the StringBuilder class need not be initialized and since it uses more basic operations.
Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
string newString = 
 String.Concat(
        originalString.Substring(0, start),
        replacementText, 
        originalString.Substring(end));
```

OR

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(originalString);
sb
  .Remove(start, length)
  .Insert(start, replacementText);
```

Comment: Why are you using a StringBuilder?

Comment: StringBuilder will be a little faster. String.Concat is using it internally also. For 3 portions of concatenation, however, simple '+' can work a little faster - so it is just a good practice to use StringBuilder rather than string when you mutate strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun with LINQ:

```
const string S = "I love cats, some more stuff here, we dont know how much more";
const string Dogs = "dogs";

var res = S
    .Take(7)
    .Concat(Dogs)
    .Concat(S.Where((c, i) => i > 10));

var resultString = string.Concat(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant but funny solution :

```
string myString = "I love cats, some more stuff here, we dont know how much more";

        Regex expr = new Regex("cats");
        int start = 8;
        int end = 11;
        Match m =expr.Match(myString);
        if (m.Index == start-1 && m.Length == end - (start-1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(expr.Replace(myString, "dogs")); 
        }
```