# C# Replace string by position

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am trying to replace a comma in a string.

For example, the data is the currency value of a part.

Eg. 453,27 This is the value I get from an SAP database

I need to replace the comma to a period to fix the value to the correct amount. Now sometimes, it will be in the thousands.

Eg. 2,356,34 This value needs to be 2,356.34

So, I need help manipulating the string to replace comma that is 2 characters from the end.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why should a number like 2,356,34 be stored in that way if a comma is meant to either be a thousand separator OR a decimal separator? That looks very odd to me

Comment: Also you should really show us what you've already tried

Comment: It is just the way it is coming from the database. The database saves it like that, and somehow it understands it. It did not make sense to me either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace part of string by position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015593/how-to-replace-part-of-string-by-position)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string x = "2,356,34";
if (x[x.Length - 3] == ',')
{
    x = x.Remove(x.Length - 3, 1);
    x = x.Insert(x.Length - 2, ".");
}
```

Comment: Realized that the thousand numbers also use a period for the comma. Used your code to change both problems to the correct format.

Comment: @tluck234 - that makes more sense then. You received *European* format, are attempting to read its value, but your parsing is set to *American* culture. An alternative fix would have been to *set the culture to European* at the time you parsed it. [I don't know the exact details, but look up "culture" / "thousands separator" / "decimal point"].

Answer (score 1):

```
string a = "2,356,34";
int pos = a.LastIndexOf(',');
string b = a.Substring(0, pos) + "." + a.Substring(pos+1);
```

You'll need to add a bit of checking for cases where there are no commas in the string, etc. but that's the core code.

You could also do it with a regex, but this is simple and reasonably efficient.

Comment: Just put this in. Ran like a dream. No more errors when adding to the database. The LastIndex was the key to it. I had tried something close to this, but could not figure out how to get it in that position. Thank you very much. Will mark as answer soon

Comment: This is very inefficient

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search gave me this:

```
void replaceCharWithChar(ref string text, int index, char charToUse)
{
    char[] tmpBuffer = text.ToCharArray();
    buffer[index] = charToUse;
    text = new string(tmpBuffer);
}
```

So your "charToUse" should be '.'. If it always is 2 characters from end, your index should be
text.length - 3.

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1843.htm

Comment: It should be -3 and not -2. :)

Comment: Oops, talking in phone simultaneously :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
string str = "2,356,34";
string[] newStr = str.Split(',');
str = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i <= newStr.Length-1; i++)
{
    if (i == newStr.Length-1)
    {
        str += "."+newStr[i].ToString();
    }
    else if (i == 0)
    {
        str += newStr[i].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        str += "," + newStr[i].ToString();
    }
}
string s = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you always need to replace the last comma with a period.

```
public string FixSAPNumber(string number)
{
    var str = new StringBuilder(number);
    str[number.LastIndexOf(',')] = '.';
    return str.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string item_to_replace = "234,45";

var item = decimal.Parse(item_to_replace);

var new_item = item/100;

//if you need new_item as string 
//then new_item.ToString(Format)
```