# String manipulation and Splitting

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, ascii

I have a data `string data2 = " %04%02%BC%94%BA%15%E3%AA%08%00%7F%00";` I am trying to split every two digits between the `%` sign and put it into an array.

In addition to that, if there is extra digit, i.e. more than 2 digits, convert to Hex and add it to the array.

My code is working sometimes, but when I add extra digit in the second last position, it gives wrong values.

```
 string data = " %04F%02%BC%94%BA%15%E3%AA%08%00%7FF%00";

        List<string> Values = new List<string>();

        string[] val = Regex.Split(data2, "%");
        byte[] TempByte = new byte[val.Length - 1];


        for (int i = 0; i < val.Length; i++)
        {
            Values.Add(val[i]);

            if (Values[i].Length > 2)
            {
                //count
                int count = 0;
                int n = 2;                       //start from digit 2(if ther is any)
                foreach (char s in Values[i])
                {
                    count++;
                }
                int index = count - 2;         //index starting at 2

                while (n <= Values[i].Length -1)    
                {
                    string temp = string.Join(string.Empty, Values[i].Substring(n, 1).Select(c =>
                                                        ((int)c).ToString("X")).ToArray());


                    Values.Add(temp);
                    n = n + 1;
                }
                //remove the extra digit
                Values[i] = Values[i].Replace(Values[i].Substring(2, 1), string.Empty);

            }
        }


        Values.RemoveAt(0);                        //since digit 0 is always zero
        string[] TagTemp = Values.ToArray();

//Convert to array

        for (int i = 0; i < val.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            TempByte[i] = Convert.ToByte(TagTemp[i], 16);
        }
```

When extra digit is added to the first position, i.e `04F`, the output is correct:

[image]

When it is added second last position, i.e `7FF` instead of `7F 46` it gives just `7`.

[image]

Do you guys see what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: How is the output correct? How do you get `46` from either `0x04` or `0x4F`, depending on how you want to treat the extra hex digits?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe - `04F` is translated into `04 46`. `F` is converted into hex

Comment: and how is that "correct"? `0x04F` is `79`. `0x04` is `4`. `0x4F` is still `79`. How do you get `04 46` from `0x04F`. In no number system that I'm familiar with does this happen...

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, no it is not like that.. the `04` is left as it is, just the extra `F` is converted, which is `46`..  it is some kind of protocol..

Comment: Oh, OK. You've got `%04` `"F"` `%02`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     string data = " %04F%02%BC%94%BA%15%E3%AA%08%00%7FF%00";

     // You need to pick an encoding -- are these things ASCII?
     var encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
     var values = new List<byte>();

     // Walk over the data (note that we don't increment here).
     for (int i = 0; i < data.Length;)
     {
        // Is this the start of an escaped byte?
        if (data[i] == '%')
        {
           // Grab the two characters after the '%'.
           var escaped = data.Substring(i + 1, 2);
           //Console.WriteLine(escaped);

           // Convert them to a byte.
           byte value = Convert.ToByte(escaped, 16);
           values.Add(value);

           // Increment over the three characters making up the escaped byte.
           i += 3;
        }
        else
        {
           // It's a non-escaped character.
           var plain = data[i];
           //Console.WriteLine(plain);

           // Convert it to a single byte.
           byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(new[] { plain });
           Debug.Assert(bytes.Length == 1);
           byte value = bytes[0];

           values.Add(value);

           // Increment over that character.
           i += 1;
        }
     }

     // Print it out, in hex, separated by commas.
     Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",
                       values.Select(v => string.Format("{0:X2}", v))));

     // Alternatively...
     Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(values.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert a three-digit hexadecimal string to a byte. The maximum value a byte can hold is FF.

Answer (score 1):

`Values[i].Replace(Values[i].Substring(2, 1), string.Empty);` is replacing both F's rather than just the one

[String.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx)

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050858/c-sharp-replace-string-by-position) for an example of positional replace.

Comment: the index `substring(2,1)` refers to the third digit i think.. also it works well when extra character is added to other positions, like the one i showed above..

Comment: see the MSDN link I supplied: `String.Replace()` returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character in this instance are replaced with another specified Unicode character. `Substring(2,1)` finds the F, `Replace()` replaces them all.