# How to overwrite a string with another string?

Tags: c#, string, overwrite

How can I overwrite a string ? Example:

```
string text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".OverwriteWith("hello world", 3);
// text == "abchello worldopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Of course this method doesn't exist. But

- Is there something build in in .NET Framework ?
- If not, how can I efficiently write a string into another string ?

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use [`String.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx) and [`String.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx) method like;

```
string text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
if(text.Length > "hello world".Length + 3)
{
   text = text.Remove(3, "hello world".Length).Insert(3, "hello world");
   Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Output will be;

```
abchello worldopqrstuvwxyz
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/J5lO7o).

Remember, strings are [*immutable types*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) in .NET. You *can't* change them. Even if you think you change them, you actually create a new string objects.

If you want to work with mutable strings, take a look at [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class.

> This class represents a string-like object whose value is a mutable
>   sequence of characters. The value is said to be mutable because it can
>   be modified once it has been created by appending, removing,
>   replacing, or inserting characters.

Comment: Make sure you test first if this string is long enough. If 3 + 11 is bigger than the length of the string, you'll get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException according MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx

Comment: @BenVanHees In OP case this is not necessary but added it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for stealing part of my answer without credit @SonerGönül :P

Comment: @Gusdor Do you think before your answer, I wasn't aware of the terms called `immutable`? Nice thought...

Comment: @SonerGönül I am questioning your integrity, not your knowledge. We communicated the same detail in the same order and same format with only a 3 word difference. Even disregarding the flagrant plagiarism, repetition of the information is redundant. Tell me, what prompted the edits?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, you cannot. Strings are an immutable type. This means that once they are created, they cannot be modified.

If you want to manipulated strings in memory, the c++ way, you should use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

You can Try this Solution this may help you..

```
  var theString = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
  var aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(theString);
  aStringBuilder.Remove(3, 2);  //Used to Remove the 
  aStringBuilder.Replace();  //Write the Required Function in the Replace
  theString = aStringBuilder.ToString();
```

Reference : [Click Here!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015593/how-to-replace-part-of-string-by-position)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an extension method:

```
static class StringEx
{
    public static string OverwriteWith(this string str, string value, int index)
    {
        if (index + value.Length < str.Length)
        {
            // Replace substring
            return str.Remove(index) + value + str.Substring(index + value.Length);
        }
        else if (str.Length == index)
        {
            // Append
            return str + value;
        }
        else
        {
            // Remove ending part + append
            return str.Remove(index) + value;
        }
    }
}

// abchello worldopqrstuvwxyz
string text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".OverwriteWith("hello world", 3);
// abchello world
string text2 = "abcd".OverwriteWith("hello world", 3);
// abchello world
string text3 = "abc".OverwriteWith("hello world", 3);
// hello world
string text4 = "abc".OverwriteWith("hello world", 0);
```